# How to abort if ssh control socket already exists?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, command-line, scripting

I'm using the following line in my scripts:

```
ssh -f -N -M -S <control socket> <host>
```

This means the initial connection just stays in the background and I can use it for subsequent calls to `ssh`:

```
ssh -S <control socket> <host> <command>
```

However, if I have multiple scripts with commands which are supposed to use the same control socket and put the "background" call to `ssh` into all of them, I will get the following message at some point:

> ```
> ControlSocket <control socket> already exists, disabling multiplexing
> ```

This has no influence over the rest of the script because obviously the socket exists and can be used by the subsequent `ssh` commands. However, even though the "background" session couldn't open the socket, it doesn't quit and stays active - just without multiplexing.

Using `[ -S` or `ssh -O check` to check the existence of the socket would still leave the possibility of race conditions.

How can I do "open control socket if it doesn't exist yet, and exit if it does"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for `ControlMaster auto`, which can be either specified in configuration file or directly on command-line with `-o ControlMaster=auto`.

This allows you to unify the commands opening the connection and using it (also very helpful with `ControlPersist`).

Comment: Unfortunately, the `-M` sets it to master, which is not what you want for transparent usage of the multiplexing.

Comment: I still get the error even with ControlMaster auto