# Have ssh fail if control socket already exists with `ControlMaster yes`

Tags: ssh

I am calling ssh with the session I want to be the control master so I am using `-M` flag (equivalent would be having `ControlMaster yes`).

However, if the previous session failed and left a zombie control file then ssh will just log `ControlSocket <control socket path> already exists, disabling multiplexing` and still make the connection. That means the control socket actually isn't setup for latter sessions (that will be `ControlMaster no`).

Is there a way to instead have ssh fail if the control socket file already exists so my script can detect and report the issue? I could have the script check for the control file, but would require the script would have to assume the control path (which can be non-obvious due to settings in the ssh config like host aliases and ControlPath).

Note this question is a bit different from
[How to abort if ssh control socket already exists?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/580994/how-to-abort-if-ssh-control-socket-already-exists). That question is asking about a control path file being present due to an existing control session, while this one is due to a failed previous session. We also want this session to be master so it can control the multiplexing. So simply removing `-M` won't solve this. Thx!

Comment: Try first with `ssh -O check` with the same `-S` (`ControlPath`) option you're using with `-M` -- you will get a different error if the file exists but ssh cannot connect to it. But better just remove it or use a unique name for the socket.